# Getting an syntax error while creating table used sequence and nextval

Tags: mysql, sql

`getting an syntax error in mysql`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE users_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('users_id_seq'),
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

create a table with id sequence but getting syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're getting are due to the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement, which is [Oracle syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) for generating auto-incremental values.

In MySQL you can use the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) keyword inside the table creation statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t77dzrrGtuH8noL1Ng6fmA/1).